# jpa identifies varchars as BLOB?

Tags: oracle, spring, jpa, openjpa

I have a pretty big but very common JPA entity class hold fields and relations. When I try to compile the project, I got this excepton:

```
-Exception Message 
Invalid column type: getBLOB not implemented for class     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor; nested exception is <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990     fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid column type: getBLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor FailedObject: com.transoftinc.vlm.carrierweb.domain.oc.Depot-SOMEDEPOT [java.lang.String]
```

--update--
Here the `SOMEDEPOT` is actually the value of `name` field to Depot entity

```
@Column(name = "D_NAME")
private String name;
```

From the exception it seems one of the fields or relations is identified as BLOB, which is not real. So please give me a hint that anyone have experienced before. Thank you.

By the way, I am running OpenJPA with Spring 3.0 and Oracle 11g.

Comment: How is the field annotated or otherwise configured?

Comment: @Aaron Sheffey The only annotations I use for this entity is `@column`, `@Transient`, `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. Thanks

Comment: Can u post a code snippet of the field `SOMEDEPOT` (I'm assuming from the posted error that that's the name of the field)

Comment: @Aaron Sheffey Please see update in the post. Thank you.

Comment: Why not post the entire class...do you include Blob in the class (accidentally)

Comment: Please post the entire Entity.